# How I can select a partition to install fedora?

Tags: fedora, partition, system-installation, live-usb

I have a problem on installing fedora.

I have already installed windows 8, and I have two different partitions (C (for windows), and D(for data)).

I had also shrink the size of D by 50 GB, in order to create this free space to install fedora.

However the fedora installer recognises only one disc, and not all the partitions I have made. Therefore it is possible that if I install fedora, my windows installation might be lost.

What should I do? I just want to install linux at that specific 50GB partition...

Thanks in advance

John

Comment: As far as I know, it has something to do with the primary partitions. I think windows 8 occupies 2 primary partitions and leaves just one primary partition for fedora. This might be the problem. This may be the reason but am not exactly sure.

Comment: @Ramesh thanks for the answer. I do not know about this, but even then, I think that It shouldn't be a problem for fedora to at least identify the number of disc partitions.

Comment: I guess fedora requires atleast 2 primary partitions (one for /boot and another for /swap or /). So, in that case fedora might not be able to detect the disc partitions.

Comment: Are all 3 partitions on the same physical disk or do you have multiple disks? Could you show us a screenshot of the partitions the installer shows you? Is there some kind of "expert mode"?

Comment: @JohnSmith in 50GB is there any filesystem or it's unallocated space ? if there is no filesystem then what's the issue while installing ? if possible also update screen shot of partitions from disk mgmt

Comment: This info might be helpful: http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1146688-how-to-dual-boot-fedora-18-and-windows-8-on-1-hdd-with-grub-in-a-pbr/

Answer (score 1):

I think what's happening is that the... quirks... in the newly-rewritten installer are frightening you, and you're stopping before getting to the part where it would all make sense. There is a first stage where you choose which disks to use *at all*. The installer doesn't look at the partitions until after you choose the disks, and **will not** write or destroy anything until it very clearly says that it's going to (and gives you a chance to cancel).

So, select your one disk, and then you'll get to the next section where you can work with the partitions. I promise: it'll be safe even though it is confusing and seems like it might be dangerous.

The installer team is aware of this issue and is working on a better user interface design for Fedora 20 and onward. But that's how it is for now.

(Disclaimer: I work for Red Hat on Fedora, but not on the installer team.)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the limitations of the MBR. If you had a GPT (GUID Partition Table) you wouldn't have any problem.

it is possible to use logical partitions instead of primary partitions for the swap, /boot, /, and /home partitions

You will not have any problem. You have to create an extended partition (which is a primary special partition/placeholder) and inside this extended partition you can create a large number of logicals. Linux can boot from logical partition, in contrast with Windows which cannot.